# Laravel Session not persisting when redirecting after adding data to the session

Tags: php, session, laravel-5

I am trying to save some `key => values` in the session before i redirect to `Twitter OAUth page`. The session is not persisting any data.

I have tested this in `centos`, `ubuntu` both running `php5.6`

> PHP 5.6.16 (cli) (built: Nov 26 2015 08:01:30) Copyright (c) 1997-2015
>   The PHP Group
>
> Apache version Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (CentOS) Server built:
>   Dec 14 2015 18:39:31

I get no errors, the storage folder is writable and i get not errors at all.

Can someone please help me with this issues.

It turns out that no file is being written ("storage/framework/sessions").

The value `'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file')`, is coming through, it doesn't work either if i change it to `'driver' => 'file'`,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the Session working, the routes are supposed be declared within the following definition in routes.php

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () { 

    });
```

Thanks